# Prove the following [Trigonometric Equation]

Tags: trigonometry

The equation to be proved is : 
$$\frac{\cot A \cos A }{\cot A + \cos A} = \frac{\cot A - \cos A} {\cot A \cos A}$$

I have tried taking both LHS and RHS to solve it, but I have not been able to solve it.

Comment: Show us what you've done.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:** prove instead that $\cot^2 A \cos^2 A = (\cot A+\cos A)(\cot A-\cos A)$.

> $$(\cot A+\cos A)(\cot A-\cos A) = \cot^2 A-\cos^2 A = \cot^2 A(1-\sin^2 A) = \cot^2 A\cos^2 A$$

Comment: Added the missing $A$, which was a simple typo.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** $$\cos^2 A=\frac{\cot^2A}{1+\cot^2 A}$$

Answer (score 0):

**Hint** Replace
$$\cos(A)=\cot(A) \sin(A)$$

Answer (score 0):

HINT: it is equivalent to $\cos(A)^2=1-\sin(A)^2$ and the left side of the equation is $$\frac{\cos(A)}{1+\sin(A)}$$ and the right side is given by $$\frac{1-\sin(A)}{\cos(A)}$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiply every numerator and denominator by $\tan(A)$. You'll get $$\dfrac{\cos(A)}{1+\sin(A)}=\dfrac{1-\sin(A)}{\cos(A)}$$. The rest has to be obvious.

Answer (score 0):

Substitute: $$\cot A = \frac{\cos A}{\sin A}$$

After simplifying the resulting equation (Hint: you will need to use the formula $a^2 - b^2=(a+b)(a-b)$) you will get:
$$1-\sin A \over \cos A$$

Multiply and divide by $\cot A$ and simplify.

Answer (score 0):

$\frac { \cot { A\cos { A }  }  }{ \cot { A+\cos { A }  }  } =\frac { \frac { \cos { A }  }{ \sin { A }  } \cdot \cos { A }  }{ \frac { \cos { A }  }{ \sin { A }  } +\cos { A }  } =\frac { \cos { A }  }{ 1+\sin { A }  } \\ $
if you multiply both deminator and nominator by $1-\sin { A } $ you will get right eqution

Answer (score 0):

LHS=$\frac{cot A cos A}{cot A+cos A}$.................convert to sin and cos
    $=\frac{\frac{cos A}{sin A}cos A}{\frac{cos A}{sin A}+cos A}$
$=\frac{\frac{cos A}{sin A}}{\frac{1}{sin A}+1}$
$=\frac{cos A}{1+sin A}$
$=\frac{cos A}{1+sin A}\times \frac{1-sin A}{1-sin A}$
$=\frac{(cos A)(1+sin A)}{1-sin^2 A}$
$=\frac{(cos A)(1-sin A)}{cos^2 A}$
$=\frac{(1-sin A)}{cos A}$
$=\frac{\frac{(1-sin A)}{sin A}}{\frac{cos A}{sin A}}$
$=\frac{\frac{(1-sin A)}{sin A}\times cos A}{\frac{cos A}{sin A}\times cos A}$
$=\frac{{(1-sin A)}\times cot A}{{cot A}\times cos A}$
$=\frac{cot A-cos A}{{cot A }\times cos A}$
$RHS$